# Store form input data without posting form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I was wondering, we have this front-end delivered by a third party. They made the design implemented this in a PHP website (Symphony based, irrelevant to my issue I believe).

The problem is, they used a lot of Javascript, which is nice for the dynamic parts. However when submitting the form, the data is being transferred through jQuery $.ajax or post too. Meaning the client side will never store the user's input for future use, which is actually something they'll want since this front end is designed for re-use ever x weeks or per month.

Anyone know if there is a way to make the form behave like if it's being posted?

As addition, the user is NOT logged in, and there could be multiple users allthough it's likely it's his private system, or shared at home. High chance it'll even be a mobile device.

Comment: Are you talking about login form ? You can store data locally using localStorage but that depends on your requirement..

Comment: Is it the same user (browser) that is going to fill in the form, or is it different users on different browsers?

Comment: Why would you store the data on the clients side? Why not storing it on server side in the database and put it out when the user is logged in or something?

Comment: Because the user does not log in, we have the data sure, but it's anonymous, having the forms store the data for the user so they can autocomplete is just saving time.

Localstorage might be our solution in the end but if a simpler way can be done that could be better. I guess it'll be localstorage

Comment: @vlarsson It should be the same user, on one or more browsers, but it's just for this browser. In most cases it'll be a mobile phone or the same web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies to save the form data, preferably after the submit. I like to use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) when working with stuff like this. I would do something like this. This will only work on a single browser.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Fetch the submit_form_input cookie that was set after submitting the form
    var submit_form_input =  JSON.parse($.cookie("submit_form_input"));

    //  Loop through the values inside the cookie
    for (i = 0; i < submit_form_input.length; i++) { 

        // Find the form with the correct id and set the value on it
        $("#" + submit_form_input[i].name).val(submit_form_input[i].value);
    }

    $("#submit_form").submit(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('action'); 
        var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(response)
               {
                   // Set the cookie
                   $.cookie("submit_form_input", data);

                   alert('Thank you for submitting the form.'); 
               }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lukrdfvx/2/).